# Is there any way to delete from this postgres 9.6 view?

Tags: postgresql

Here is the view:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE RECURSIVE VIEW employees_recursive(id, name, child_category_id,parent_category_id, level,topic_id, type_name, inserted_at, updated_at) AS
(
    SELECT
        ee.id,
        ee.name,
        child_category_id,
        parent_category_id,
        1 as level,
        ct.id,
        ct.name,
        ee.inserted_at,
        ee.updated_at
    FROM category_hierarchy cth
    LEFT JOIN categories ee ON cth.child_category_id = ee.id
    INNER JOIN category_types ct ON ee.topic_id = ct.id
    WHERE
        parent_category_id IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ee.id,
        ee.name,
        c.child_category_id,
        c.parent_category_id,
        ct.id,
        ct.name,
        ee.inserted_at,
        ee.updated_at
    FROM employees_recursive p
    INNER JOIN category_hierarchy c ON p.child_category_id = c.parent_category_id
    LEFT JOIN categories ee ON c.child_category_id = ee.id
    INNER JOIN category_types ct ON ee.topic_id = ct.id
)
```

I've been trying to write a function to delete rows from the view by id using functions and triggers [following this post](https://vibhorkumar.blog/2011/10/28/instead-of-trigger/).  The Postgres docs say that views with "WITH" or "UNION" keywords at the top level are not updateable.

does that mean I can't delete rows from this view?

If that's the case, is there a way to delete rows from the actual table and somehow refresh the view?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, afaik, *any* view can be "updatable" but only views that are “simple enough” can be **automatically** updatable. You can make any `VIEW` updatable with

- [`INSTEAD OF` trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/trigger-definition.html) trigger
- [PostgreSQL RULE SYSTEM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-views.html#RULES-VIEWS-UPDATE) I prefer to never use the rule system.

And of course you can make a function that works on the underlying table and updates it.

Comment: A RULE isn't the only way to make a VIEW updateable. The recommended way is an `instead of` trigger.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good point, updated.